# Hadoop installed - issue with root

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I have installed **Hadoop 1.2.1 from Apache** on a user account in Ubuntu but **not on root**. When I issue commands, I add **sudo**. The problem is when I start hadoop using '**sudo bin/start-all.sh**' from hadoop home dir, it keeps asking me root password as shown in the snapshot before it starts datanode, before it starts secondarynamenode etc. What do I do to avoid entering the root password?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable passwordless sudo by editing /etc/sudoers for this, check here,

https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux

But you need to be very careful when editing the /etc/sudoers file, it's better to use visudo instead of vi directly, or enable another linux account with sudo access. Otherwise if you did something wrong with /etc/sudoers, you will lose the ability to sudo. I've came to this awkward situation before...

Comment: Thanks Lex. I will give it a try and let you know